# Run task alternatively on celery django python

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

Suppose there are two task 1 and 2

In a span of 30 min run

- task1 - 15min later
- task2 - 15min later
- task1 - 15min later
  and so on...

Instead of running same task every 15 min run them alternatively

So far have tried

```html
'task1-FifteenMinutes': {
       'task': 'task1',
       'schedule': crontab(minute='*/15'),
    },
```

No luck on task2